# Has anyone had experience canning with "Quattro Stagioni" Jars?

Tags: canning

I am in the midst of canning a variety of items that require either boiling water bath  processing or pressure canning. I usually use a two part lid and screw band (Ball or Kerr) with jars, but this year I found some really pretty [jars made by Quattro Stagioni](https://www.containerstore.com/s/kitchen/food-storage/quattro-stagioni-glass-canning-jars/12d?productId=10013117&gclid=CjwKCAjw4_H6BRALEiwAvgfzq2IfDWh3HzoL5lLfPhZt4JcgZU07aoV_CLtSSMdemK280ydk4HiaTBoCz2sQAvD_BwE), that have one piece lids. There are directions for canning included, but they don't really advise whether the lids are appropriate for pressure canning. I am hoping that someone may have experience and can lend their advice to me.

Comment: I don't personally can, but I found a [blog post](http://farmnatters.blogspot.com/2010/02/bisphenol-and-canning-lids.html) that mentions "Quattro Stagioni lids (which I don't even know if they'll work with standard Ball or Kerr jars like I have) are also BPA-free and can be used in a pressure canner." ... of course, that's only the lids, not the jars.

Comment: I have used Quattro Staggioni jars for canning when using a boiling water bath as the processing method.  Worked fine for a variety of preserves, both high-acid and low-acid.  Sorry, no experience with a pressure canner.

Answer (score 2):

I live in Italy - the Quattro Stagioni brand here has been around for more than 30 years, and it is considered the golden standard for in-house canning (other Bormioli glass products are well regarded, too); everyone I know who canned something in his or her life have been using them, and I've never heard of anybody saying anything but great stuff about them. It's rare that I go a whole month without eating something that is coming out of a Quattro Stagioni jar. The one-piece lids are indeed very handy, even if they are a bit pricey (but you probably already noticed that).

All of the Bormioli material (website) and instructions (I'm reading them now from the lid packaging) only mention canning with boiling (pasteurization to be precise), and I've only seen them used that way. This restricts the type of foods you can can (pun not intended) to highly-acidic ones: fruit conserves, tomato sauces, pickled vegetables, etc.

Of course, for maximum hygiene you should follow the instructions to the letter, and use a new cap every time. However, I've seen people successfully re-use caps for canning with less spoil-prone foods (e.g. pickled vegetables), but this is anedoctal and I don't think I can really suggest it.

The lid packaging also report a toll-free number “grandmother Amelia info” (not joking), but unfortunately it's late now as I write; I might call next Monday if I have time.

Happy canning!